# Creating EC2 Instance with more than 30gb - In Java

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, sdk, instance

When I build an EC2 instance m1.small (for example), by deafult I get 30gb instead of 160gb.

I've seen in google that I need to add ephemeral storage / instance stored storage..
To my question:
Is there a way to add the ephemeral storage using the java sdk?
If I create an instance (using the sdk) with a standard volume of 160gb, I get charged as if I was creating a regular instance and attached a new volume to it?

And more generally, so when they write that an instance has 160gb, 
that means I only have 30gb and another 140gb that I should only use for temporary files which i dont mind to lose?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You should not try to make the heap size much larger than the main memory size. AFAIK EC2 don't offer machines with more than 160 GB of main memory (I could be wrong) http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/instance-types/

If you are talking about this instance

```
M1 Small Instance – default++

1.7 GiB memory
 1 EC2 Compute Unit (1 virtual core with 1 EC2 Compute Unit)
 160 GB instance storage
 32-bit or 64-bit platform
 I/O Performance: Moderate
 EBS-Optimized Available: No
 API name: m1.small
```

This reads as, you can use a heap of about 1.2 to 1.5 GB and 160 GB of local disk space.

AFAIK, You can access storage as regular files.

BTW: Java can take increasing long time to perform a Full GC on large heap sizes.  The worst time can be 1 second per 1-4 GB depending on your system.  You could expect that a system with a 160 GB heap can see 40 second stop-the-world GCs.

For this reason, off heap options are often explored such as using a database, BigMemory or use direct memory/memory mapped files.

Comment: I know it's a ten year old thread - does AWS support MMF? If one EC2 instance die, is the state going to die with it as well?

Comment: @Abidi AWS support MultiMode Fibre, however, I suspect you are asking if the state of services is retained, and I suspect you need to have the state stored in a datastore to ensure that.